# Chef recipe to restart rsyslog

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, rsyslog

I've got a recipe that should install a template, and then restart the service...

```
service "rsyslog" do
  supports :restart => true, :reload => true
  action [:enable, :start]
end 

Chef::Log.info("Creating loggly rsyslog conf")
template "/etc/rsyslog.d/22-loggly.conf" do
  source "syslogd.conf.erb"
  mode "0755"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  notifies :restart, resources(:service => "rsyslog")
end
```

Why am I getting:

```
ERROR: resource template[/etc/rsyslog.d/22-loggly.conf] is configured to notify resource service['rsyslog'] with action restart, but service['rsyslog'] cannot be found in the resource collection. template[/etc/rsyslog.d/22-loggly.conf] is defined in /home/ubuntu/cookbooks/loggly-syslog/recipes/default.rb:7:in `from_file'

[2014-01-03T23:26:37+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

How can I make rsyslog restart/reload after I add the config file??

Comment: I just wrote an answer, but are you sure that service resource is defined exactly as you've listed?

Comment: I ask, because you may be encountering the error I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370804/how-do-i-check-if-a-folder-exists-in-chef/20908633#20908633

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the old notification syntax. Switch to the new syntax:

```
template '...' do
  notifies :restart, 'service[rsyslog]'
end
```

Comment: To be fair the [service document still uses both forms of notification syntax](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_service.html) - I know it confused me about if one notification completely replaced the other or if there was usage cases for both - [foodcritic is so helpful](http://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic/#FC043). I've emailed docs@getchef to see if they update this.

Comment: Great. He's on the case as we speak - and the change will go live later.

Comment: Yup - I'm watching the build go through now

Comment: I am using the new syntax and still no luck:

template "..." do
    notifies :restart, "service[mysql]", :immediately
end

Due to the fact that "service[mysql] cannot be found in the resource collection". This is stated on the link @sethvargo posted in the comments of the question. I'm not sure how this or the other post are marked as solved. :/ Can anyone explain where/how to add it to the collection? I can do the same thing with php-fpm without warning:

template "..." do
    notifies :restart, "service[php5-fpm]", :immediately
end

Can someone tell me what we're missing here??

Comment: Correction, the "other" post is answered as it's related, but a different question.

Comment: @sethvargo I thing that is not and answer. I have similar issue, because I am trying to avoid WARNING of cloning resource. I have service resource in 1 recipe (aka recipe1 where I started it), but I am stopping it in another recipe (aka recipe2).

When running RSpecs to test (only) recipe1 I got that error. Any help on this ?